# POST Javascript generated file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

Using fabric.js, I am adding some text overlays to a user's local image, and then shoving it into an

```
<img src="" id="pic" style="display: none;">
```

Now, I need to POST it to my server.I know how to upload files justing HTML and an

```
<input type="file" id="popup_chooser" name="something">
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get $('#pic').attr('src') into a POST variable.

How is the best way to go about doing this?
Thanks

Comment: What is `$('#pic').attr('src')`? Is it a data url an object url a regular url etc...

Comment: I've tried using a hidden input and setting it's value. This works, sort of. It comes up in $_POST instead of $_FILES where I'd like it to. However, I *can* live with this. If there is a better way, I'd rather use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could [serialize the image data](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#serialization) and POST it with a hidden input: `<input type="hidden" name="img_src" value="[your image data]">`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right it could be something like :

```
$('#popup_chooser').val($('#pic').attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input with a id and change it's value on submit.

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="srcid" ... //html
```

and with jQuery:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    $('#srcid').prop('value') == $('#pic').prop('src');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have an input field of type hidden.

```
<form>
<img src="" id="pic" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" id='pic_hidden' value="" name="pic_hidden" />
</form>
```

Then have javascript mirror changes to the src:

```
$('#pic_hidden').attr('value', $('#pic').attr('src') )
```